# Webpack: cannot resolve module 'file-loader'

Tags: sass, webpack

When I try to build ***SASS*** file with webpack, I got the following error:

> Module not found: Error:Cannot resolve module 'file-loader'

note that this issue only happen when i try to load background image using relative path.

this Work fine:

```
  background:url(http://localhost:8080/images/magnifier.png);
```

this cause the issue:

```
   background:url(../images/magnifier.png);
```

and this is my project structure

- images
- styles
- webpack.config.js

and this is my webpack file:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        build: [
            './scripts/app.jsx',
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        filename: 'public/[name].js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {test: /\.jsx?$/, loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel?stage=0'], exclude: /node_modules/},
            {test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'sass']},
            {test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
            {test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/, loader: 'file-loader'}
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss', '.eot', '.ttf', '.svg', '.woff'],
        modulesDirectories: ['node_modules', 'scripts', 'images', 'fonts']
    }
};
```

Comment: css-loader converts every `url(...)` into `require(...)`, so `../images/magnifier.png` gets picked up by the `/\.(png|jpg)$/` test. Do you have file-loader installed?

Comment: @silvenon, thanks for your response ***file-loader*** was broken so i re-installed it, and everything gonna fine.Thanks

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As @silvenon said in his comment:

> Do you have file-loader installed?

yes ***file-loader*** was installed but broken, and my issue has been solved by re-installing it.

`npm install --save-dev file-loader`

Comment: For those who want to use [`url-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader): you also have to install [`file-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader) for it, so run `npm install --save-dev file-loader`.

Comment: What if I don't want webpack to load files? I do not need webpack to check if the image really exists in the dist folder.

Comment: Thank you! Spent a long time trying to fix a similar error where /node_modules/@ionic/core/dist/ionic/svg/index.js was giving an error when trying to run unit tests and only happened when using Ionic Platform

Comment: Thank you! Worked for me after I installed it.

Answer (score 7):

You may face a **very similar issue** if you are using `url-loader` with the `limit` configuration defined. [As the documentation states](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader), if the resource you are trying to load exceeds this **limit**, then `file-loader` will be used as fallback. Therefore, if you do not have `file-loader` installed, an error will prompt. To fix this error, set this limit to a bigger value or do not define it at all.

```js
      {
        test: /\.(jpg|png|svg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 50000, // make sure this number is big enough to load your resource, or do not define it at all.
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 4):

I has the exactly same issue and the following fixed it:

```
loader: require.resolve("file-loader") + "?name=../[path][name].[ext]"
```

Comment: This looks very useful, but I'm having trouble mapping it into the webpack.config with the other loader configs. Could you possibly provide a more complete example? Do you mean like this? 
`{test: /\.(png|jpg)$/, loader: require.resolve("file-loader") + "?name=../[path][name].[ext]"}
`

Comment: Hi @Ihahne, did you use yarn? I had the same issue, I only could resolve with this command. But I didn't know why.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this - this was the final piece to get
 Bootstrap, d3js, Jquery, base64 inline images and my own badly written JS to play with webpack.

To answer the question above and the solution to getting around the problematic
**Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'url'**
When compiling bootstrap fonts was

```
{ 
test: /glyphicons-halflings-regular\.(woff2|woff|svg|ttf|eot)$/,
loader:require.resolve("url-loader") + "?name=../[path][name].[ext]"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue while running jest, then add this in **moduleNameMapper**

```
"ace-builds": "<rootDir>/node_modules/ace-builds"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Error - ./node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.cssdisabled.
     Error: Module not found: Can't resolve 'url-loader'
```

Fixed by installing `url-loader`, ex:
`run 'npm install url-loader --save-dev'`